# Dynamically passed function parameter for JS through php, is showing error that undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have passed a parameter for js function in onclick event through php, but on click it is saying in console that parameter is undefined.

code in php

```
<?php
echo "<div style='background-image: url($thumbnail);' onclick='showImageInDiv(dfds)'></div>";

?>

function showImageInDiv(dfdss){

        alert(dfdss);
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dfds is not defined
```

Comment: echo "<div class='fl-product-page-single-gallery-container' style='background-image: url($thumbnail);' onclick='showImageInDiv(\"dfds\")'></div>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check quotes, you need to give quotes or else it will consider it as javascript variable, which is undefined.

```
echo "<div class='fl-product-page-single-gallery-container'  
style='background-image: url($thumbnail);'  
onclick='showImageInDiv(\"$thumbnail\")'></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are passing a variable

```
onclick='showImageInDiv(dfds)'
```

Instead of passing a string

```
onclick='showImageInDiv(\'dfds\')'
```

That's why it's saying

> error: Uncaught ReferenceError: dfds is not defined

Because dfds is not a string but a variable